# Export DB2 select to CSV with headhers

Tags: csv, db2, export

I am trying to export DB2 select with headhers. But without any success, my actual code is:

```
db2 "EXPORT TO /tmp/result5.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL 
SELECT 1 as id, 'DEVICE_ID', 'USER_ID' from sysibm.sysdummy1 
UNION ALL (SELECT 2 as id, DEVICE_ID, USER_ID FROM MOB_DEVICES) ORDER BY id"
```

which is not working (I suggest because USER_ID is INTEGER), when I change it for:

```
db2 "EXPORT TO /tmp/result5.csv OF DEL MODIFIED BY NOCHARDEL 
SELECT 1 as id, 'DEVICE_ID', 'PUSH_ID' from sysibm.sysdummy1 
UNION ALL (SELECT 2 as id, DEVICE_ID, PUSH_ID FROM MOB_DEVICES) ORDER BY id"
```

It works, DEVICE_ID and PUSH_ID are both VARCHAR.

[MOB_DEVICE TABLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9n25T.png) Any suggest how to solve this?

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DB2 will not export a CSV file with the headers, because the headers will be included as data. Normally, CSV file is for storage not viewing. If you want to view a file with its headers you have the following options:

- Export to IXF file, but this file is not a flat file. You will need a spreadsheet to view it.
- Export to a CSV file and include the headers by:

  - Select the columns names from the name, and then perform an extra step to add it to the file. You can use the describe command or perform a select on syscat.columns for this purpose, but this process is manual.
  - Perform a select union, in one part the data and in the other part the headers.
- Perform a select and take the output to a file. Do not use export.

  - select * from myTable > myTable

Comment: I created a question to ask how to get the column names in SQL http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38726949/return-a-row-in-a-db2-function-with-variable-quantity-of-scalar-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the EXPORT, thus just looking exclusively at the problematic UNION ALL query:

The DB2 SQL will want to conform the data of the mismatched data-types, into the numeric data-type; in this scenario, into the INTEGER data-type. Because conspicuously, the literal string value 'USER_ID' is not a valid representation of numeric value, that value can not be cast into an INTEGER value.

However, one can explicitly request to reverse that casting [whereby SQL wants to convert from string into numeric], to ensure that the SQL obeys the desired effect, to convert the INTEGER values from the column into VARCHAR values; i.e. explicit casting can ensure the data-types between the common columns of the UNION will be compatible, by forcing the values from the INTEGER column to *match* the data-type of the literal\constant character-string value of 'USER_ID':

```
with
  mob_devices (DEVICE_ID, USER_ID, PUSH_ID) as 
  ( values( varchar('dev', 1000 ), int( 1 ), varchar('pull', 1000) ) )
( SELECT  1 as id, 'DEVICE_ID', 'USER_ID'
  from sysibm.sysdummy1
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT  2 as id,  DEVICE_ID , cast( USER_ID as varchar(1000) )
  FROM MOB_DEVICES
) 
ORDER BY id
```